# Heat/AC Unit Cover

Tags: hvac, cover

I'm living in co-op building in northeastern part of Queens, New York and have heat/AC unit in the apartment.

Two questions:

1. What is the technical term for such unit? It's not just radiator for it has heat in winter but AC in summary.
2. I'm trying to see if there is good solution to cover the unit or make the unit looking better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Directly outside the window, is there another module?  A radiator?

Comment: do you rent or own there?  Whose responsibility is repairs?

Comment: It's a co-op so the relationship is a bit weird; technically and legally it's a lease but I tend to think I "own" it. Management office said this is pretty old unit and they can't find out who's still making these things.

Comment: After looking on my computer this system appears to have the filters on the bottom so the front cover could be solid if that is true. Without the filters dust will eventually plug the heat exchanger fins.

Comment: I mean, when you moved in there, did a Realtor help you find it, was a title search done, home inspection, mortgage lender who talked about "points" to pay upfront but reduce your mortgage, 15, 20, 30 year mortgage, a ~$1 million check to an escrow company, a condition checklist, an event called "closing" and now you pay a mortgage to a bank and an HOA type fee? That's owning.  Or did you find it on Craigslist for $xxxx/month which you pay to 'some guy'?  That's renting.

Comment: On that sense it’s owning.

Comment: `I'm trying to see if ...` is not a question

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "fan-coil unit" and it seems to be missing a front panel as its majority cause of ugliness.

Start with your building superintendent or maintenance person/department.

[Fan Coil Unit: a unit with a coil through which heated or chilled water is passed depending on the season, and a fan to blow air across that coil to heat or cool the apartment.]

Comment: The management office basically says they can't find really help here; any chance you know any contractor/company would still build such units or the covers/parts of them?

Comment: Yup, it is missing a cover.

Comment: Any NYC-area heating/air-conditioning contractor that works in apartment buildings should be able to find something to sort that. Or any custom sheet-metal fabricator, but likely cheaper if you can find a supplier that has the mass-manufactured part you need in stock.

Comment: I haven’t seen a package unit with chilled water normally they use a refrigerant or all the ones I have worked on were “Freon” based. But who knows in newyork it could be water based.

Comment: It's not a package unit. It's a large-scale city-type apartment building, which means boiler hot water and chilled water, not little heat pumps in each unit. It's a fan-coil unit, as stated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missing the front access panel. It's probably quite loud without it. Just make one from thin plywood and attach with some velcro or sheet metal screws.

Answer (score 0):

These are called “package units” everything in 1 box.  Quite popular in hotel/  motel and studio apartments. Yes there should be a cover in the front all the ones I have worked on have been metal, if you are renting I would ask the superintendent for a cover, with how strict some have said New York electrical laws are I would this to be a violation especially in a rental.

PTAC may be the official name but through the wall self contained unit. I can’t tell if the intake is at the bottom or the cover had it that’s the normal location ~12” tall most of the front bottom.